# ASP.Net Core MVC - List<SelectListItem> multiselect not showing select = true items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making a strongly typed update/create view for "Medical Supplies" in which users can select multiple options ("Kits") from a dropdown list that received a `List<SelectListItem>`. The list is a `<select multiple="multiple">`. It was originally working perfectly, but I must have accidentally changed something.

Now the dropdown does not display SelectListItems passed to it as selected = true as selected (as verified by VS debugger), so I can select new items but not deselect previously selected ones. I need this to compare the list of IDs from the new selection to the old one in order to determine what must be removed from the Db.

This is my view model:

```cs
 public class MedicalSupplyViewModel
    {
        public MedicalSupplyViewModel()
        {
            Supply = new MedicalSupply();
            KitList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            KitIds = new List<int>();
        }

        public MedicalSupply Supply { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> KitList { get; set; }
        public string StringKits { get; set; }
        public List<int> KitIds { get; set; }

        public void KitStringSet()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> KitNames = Supply.KitSupplies.Select(ks => ks.Kit.Name);

            StringKits = Supply.KitSupplies.Count() == 0 ? "N/A" : string.Join(", " , KitNames);
        }
    }
```

This is the relevant cshtml in my view:

```cs
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="kit_select" asp-for="KitIds" asp-items="Model.KitList"></select>
```

This is the part of the controller method for this page that creates the `SelectListItems`:

```cs
DetailsModel.KitList = _db.Kits.ToList().ConvertAll(k =>
{
     return new SelectListItem()
     {
          Value = k.Id.ToString(),
          Text = k.Name,
          Selected = SelectedKits.Contains(k)
      };
});
```

Even setting the item to selected = true will not display them as such. I've set breakpoint everywhere, including in the view, and I cannot find a discrepancy between the selected property and what it should be anywhere except for the rendered html. I've also used different browsers and spent hours searching the internet and this website.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the selected items' value to the KitIds. Below is my test example:

**Model:**

```
public class MedicalSupplyViewModel
{
    public MedicalSupplyViewModel()
    {
        KitList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        KitIds = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> KitList { get; set; }
    public string StringKits { get; set; }
    public List<int> KitIds { get; set; }

}
public class Kit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Kit> kits = new List<Kit>
        {
            new Kit{ Id = 1, Name = "AA"},
            new Kit{ Id = 2, Name = "BB"},
            new Kit{ Id = 3, Name = "CC"},
        };

        List<Kit> SelectedKits = new List<Kit>
        {
            new Kit{ Id = 1, Name = "AA"},
            new Kit{ Id = 2, Name = "BB"}
        };

        var DetailsModel = new MedicalSupplyViewModel();
        DetailsModel.KitIds = SelectedKits.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        DetailsModel.KitList = kits.ToList().ConvertAll(k =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = k.Id.ToString(),
                Text = k.Name
            };
        });
        return View(DetailsModel);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="kit_select" asp-for="KitIds" asp-items="Model.KitList"></select>
```

**Result:**

[image]